# How to compare a range of values to a string in an organized fashion?

Tags: java

this is a simple question.

I have a string which I have split into an array of characters. I need to iterate through each character and check if it is the same as a relevant one that indicates certain behaviour. How can I do this without having a bunch of if/switch statements. Other than create a new method which I implement that accepts multiple arguments and compares all of them, not sure what I can do here.

Thanks.

edit: I am looking for a good implementation of a function that can do this or a java statement (i.e. if statement) that would make this process easier.

edit2: mistagged as c#, but I regularly use both languages so I don't mind an explanation in either one.

Some crappy code to illustrate a simple example of what I mean:

```
`if (charsArray[i] == "-")
    s.push(charsArray[i]);
if (charsArray[i] == "+")
    s.push(charsArray[i]);
if (charsArray[i] == "[")
    s.push(charsArray[i]);
if (charsArray[i] == "]")
    s.push(charsArray[i]);`
```

Note: I would use a for loop to iterate through each char after it is an array of characters.

Comment: Use Contains method of string.

Comment: "or a java statement" - but your question is marked C#... What language are you looking for? Showing sample code that you already have (instead of [hi/thanks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)) would make you question much better... At least function signature as "accepts multiple arguments and compares all of them" is hard to reason about.

Comment: How long is this string?  Is the position of each character relevant, or is it just whether it's in the string or not?

Comment: Can you at least show us some pseudo code? Do you literally mean finding a single character in a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the behavior is not unique for each symbol, two pretty good solutions are a switch:

```
switch(charsArray[i]) {
    case '+': case '-': case '[': case ']':
        s.push(charsArray[i]);
}
```

And String contains (this might be what the comment suggestion is referring to):

```
if("+-[]".contains(String.valueOf(charsArray[i]))) {
    s.push(charsArray[i]);
}
```

If the behavior is unique, you might use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with a HashMap:

```
// where charMap is some HashMap<Character, SomeStrategy>
SomeStrategy strat = charMap.get(charArray[i]);
if(strat != null)
    strat.execute();
```

(Which I think is the Java way to do what @bubbinator is suggesting. I don't know C# but I guess Dictionary is a hash table.)

Comment: I like this, especially the second method as it is particularly effective here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The change from C# to java occurred while I was creating this. As such, this may not work.

Simple question, semi-complicated answer.

You could create a `Dictionary <char, object>` where object is some other `Type` that will work for you. After that, in your iterating through the string, check if the `Dictionary` contains the key and then... well, you can sort it out from there. :)

A suggestion, you could use a `delegate` or one of it's child types (`Action`, `Predicate`, or `Func`). I can't be any more specific as you did not post any code...

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like an ideal way to use Dictionary. It is possible in java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html

Comment: @user2312844 Yes but you shouldn't use Hashtable (which is the concrete implementation of Dictionary). There are plenty of SO threads covering why but in short: it's old. HashMap is I guess the Java equivalent of C# Dictionary.

Comment: I'm glad someone cleared that up. I left this answer here just in case it got the gears turning for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all "uninteresting" characters from the string (by replacing them with a blank), *then* push *all* remaining chars.

It's just two lines:

```
for (char c : str.replaceAll("[^-+\\[\\]]", "").toCharArray())
    s.push(c);`
```

Comment: What for loop? Is there a for loop that produces the strings? If so, so what?

Comment: I am just confused about the arguments in `for (char c : str.replaceAll("[^-+\\[\\]]", "")`

Comment: Do you mean the expression passed to `replaceAll()`?